# Need help recovering data from hard disk formatted by Ubuntu,

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, partitioning

I am a beginner with Ubuntu. I have tried installing Ubuntu yesterday in C drive. However it took over the complete hard disk space. I dont see my data. After doing lot of research on internet got to know that with the help of disktest tool that can be recovered. I tried booting from live usb and installing testdisk on the that. I was successful in analysing the cylinders. Got to see all the NTFS derives. But once i selected one of the drive and pressed enter it did not give me any option to recover it on external disk. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look here, [How to recover a lost windows partition after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) Your Ubuntu partition took **ALL** of the space in your Windows partition, you might not be able to recover it. The only way I think you can **fully** recover is if you have an off-site back up of your windows partition and recover it